# How are Deferreds different from callbacks

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I have following piece of SharePoint JavaScript client object code which works perfectly without throwing any error.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //don't exectute any jsom until sp.js file has loaded.        
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', prepareTables);
    });

    function prepareTables() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            getItemsWithCaml('External User Account Request',
                function (camlItems) {
                    var listItemEnumerator = camlItems.getEnumerator();
                    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                        var listItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                        console.log(listItem.get_item('Title'));
                    }
                },
                function (sender, args) {
                    console.log('An error occured while retrieving list items:' + args.get_message());
                });
        }
    }    

    function getItemsWithCaml(listTitle, success, error) {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        var camlItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(camlItems);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    success(camlItems);
                },
                error
            );
    };
```

However, if I replace the same code to use deferreds/promises I get collection has not been initialized error:

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or
>   the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly
>   requested.

Following is the code using deferreds:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //don't exectute any jsom until sp.js file has loaded.        
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', prepareTables);
    });    

    function prepareTables() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            getItemsWithCaml('External User Account Request').then(
                function (camlItems) {
                    var listItemEnumerator = camlItems.getEnumerator();
                    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                        var listItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                        console.log(listItem.get_item('Title'));
                    }
                },
                function (sender, args) {
                    console.log('An error occured while retrieving list items:' + args.get_message());
                }
            );              
        }
    }    

    function getItemsWithCaml(listTitle) {
        //use of $.Deferred in the executeQueryAsync delegate allows the consumer of this method to write 'syncronous like' code
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();        
        this.items = list.getItems(camlQuery);

        clientContext.load(this.items);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this,
                function () { deferred.resolve(this.items); }),
            Function.createDelegate(this,
                function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args); }));

        return deferred.promise();
    };
```

Comment: What lines throws the error? The resolve?

Comment: `var listItemEnumerator = camlItems.getEnumerator();` throws error.

Comment: Isn't `this` changed in the delegate? Why not use a `var items = ` as you do in your first code snippet?

Comment: @RobertLindgren, that solved the issue. Can you please add it as an answer.

Comment: Great! I added it as an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an issue with `this`, since it changes scope when you use it in the delegates, try using `var items= list.getItems(camlQuery)` as you do in your first snippet:

```
function getItemsWithCaml(listTitle) {
    //use of $.Deferred in the executeQueryAsync delegate allows the consumer of this method to write 'syncronous like' code
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();        
    var items = list.getItems(camlQuery); // changed to local variable

    clientContext.load(items); //changed to load the variable

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this,
            function () { deferred.resolve(items); }), // return the variable
        Function.createDelegate(this,
            function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args); }));

    return deferred.promise();
};
```